# Function is not reading the integer from a file

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to write a function for a program I'm working on. The aim of my function is to take a number from the "text" file and use the variable store to hold that value and have current to be equal to store add 1  and output the value of current into the original text file.

but when I execute the program, with the number 1 in the text file, it appears that the store does not take the 1 from the text file and is set to be 0 when I printed the variable, while current is equal to 1 so 1 is outputted to the file. Below is the code and an example of what I'm trying to do.

If you do have suggestions, concerns, or a solution. Please feel free to comment, Thank you.

**Example:**

If text file = 1

then store = textfile(1)

and current =  store(1) + 1 | current = 2

textfile = current(2)

```
    #include <stdio.h>


main()
{
int current=0,store;

FILE*count=fopen("text","r");
FILE*countout=fopen("text","w");
fscanf(count,"%d",store);

current=store+1;

fprintf(countout,"%d",current);
fclose(count);
fclose(countout);
}
```

**Fixed Code:**

```
main()
{
int current=0,store;

FILE*count=fopen("text","r");
fscanf(count,"%d",&store);
fclose(count);

current=store+1;

printf("%d %d",store,current);

FILE*countout=fopen("text","w");
fprintf(countout,"%d",current);
fclose(countout);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you open the same file for writing that you just opened for reading? When you open a file in `"w"` mode the previous file is erased. Step 1 would be to check the result handed back to the caller by every I/O operation.

Comment: Your compiler should be telling you the code is not proper, it should issue a warning that the expected argument for a `%d` format in `fscanf` is a *pointer* to an `int`. If the compiler doesn't say anything, then enable more warnings.

Comment: @WeatherVane my apologies, I'm quite new to coding and trying to work my first program, it was just my intuition that it would separate the two pointers. I have now fixed my code.

Comment: By the time you come to read with `fscanf` (assuming the `&` fault was corrected) the file has no content, so nothing was read, and `fscanf` returns `EOF`. Always check the result of I/O operations, and *especially* file opening and input operations.

Comment: Welcome! Please don't "fix" the posted code.

Comment: @WeatherVane i added to my question "Fixed Code:" it appears that the issue was resolved, is this okay?

Comment: Ah yes: you added the new version, but you still haven't checked anything. It might just seem like a boring formality, but it is an essential part of properly functioning code.

Comment: So this is like, printing out to the console what has been inputted and outputted and so on? Am i correct

Comment: Assuming the read operation went well, it will print an integer that is read from the file and that integer plus one.